# Cannot access public properties in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, derived-class

I have an `abstract class` which is inherited by another class as following:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
}

public class OtherEmployee : Employee
    {
        public OtherEmployee()
        {
        }

        public string specialField{ get; set; }
    }
```

This is what I am doing and somehow, not getting it done:

```
Employee otherEmployee= new OtherEmployee();
otherEmployee.specialField = "somevalue";
```

I am not provided with the access to `specialField`, whereas all the attributes of `Employee` are accessible. I know it is a trivial problem, but I have hit a roadblock here..

Comment: Take a moment to thing about what the code does. You tell the compiler that `otherEmployee` is an `Employee`. And then you try to access something called `specialField`, which does not exist in the context of `Employee`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Employee` doesn't know about `specialField`, only `OtherEmployee` does. You need to cast it to the right class to use `specialField`.

```
Employee otherEmployee = new OtherEmployee();
```

This doesn't give you an `OtherEmployee` but an `Employee`. To be able to use `specialField` do something like this:

```
(otherEmployee as OtherEmployee).specialField = yourValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will not have access to `specialField` because the object is created with the base class reference. It will not have access to the Child class properties.

Though the object is instantiated with a child Class, the reference still points to base class. So the properties/skeleton will be of base class and it would not have memory allocated for child class structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write in this way beacause you daeclare otheremployee variable as Employee Type, so it doesn't know about special field. So:

```
(otherEmployee as OtherEmployee).specialField = "somevalue";
```